# Splitting one row into two based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a situation like you can see in the image:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EtZd.png)

Basically, I need to duplicate the rows where are 2 numbers splitted with '+' and then from first row remove part of the number after '+'. For second row do the opposite, remove part of the number before '+'. I need to do that for every occurrence of values with '+' in that column.

To make it clear, i need to split that one row with '+' in number into something like this:

02.05.2022 0 221350 Michaelis F Lager

02.05.2022 0 221181 Michaelis F lager

Does anyone know how i can achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": ["221350*66666", 99999,123456], "Col2": ["A", "B", "C"]})

df = df.assign(Col3=df["Col1"].str.split("*")).explode("Col3")
df["Col3"].fillna(df["Col1"], inplace=True)
print(df)
           Col1 Col2    Col3
0  221350*66666    A  221350
0  221350*66666    A   66666
1         99999    B   99999
2        123456    C  123456
```